# count most occuring characters in text

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering is there is a way to get the most occurring characters from a text? like top 5 or 10. Reading all the chars is no problem but i'm having trouble with this one. 
Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use shell utilities:

```
grep -o . filename | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

would give a count of the characters occurring in the input in descending order.

Pipe the result to `head` to get the top 5 or top 10.

For example,

```
$ echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | grep -o . | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
      8  
      4 o
      3 e
      2 u
      2 r
      2 h
      1 z
      1 y
      1 x
      1 w
      1 v
      1 T
      1 t
      1 s
      1 q
      1 p
      1 n
      1 m
      1 l
      1 k
      1 j
      1 i
      1 g
      1 f
      1 d
      1 c
      1 b
      1 a
```

---

If you wanted the count to be case-insensitive, you could insert a `tr` pipeline:

```
grep -o . filename | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `fold`

```
fold -w1 filename | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```